# How fix "Security scope definition global could not be resolved" in springfox?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am using springfox for generating swagger documentation from spring controllers. When visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mycontextroot/swagger-ui.html` I got swagger UI which **works!**

But when I try to open same `yaml` (or `json`) file generated from `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mycontextroot/v2/api-docs` but via `https://editor.swagger.io/` I got erros:

[image]

Swagger samle:

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
    description: Api Documentation
    version: '1.0'
    title: Api Documentation
    termsOfService: urn:tos
    contact: {}
    license:
        name: Apache 2.0
        url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
host: 127.0.0.1:8080
basePath: "/"
paths:
    "/mycontextroot/blogs":
        get:
            summary: blogs
            operationId: blogsUsingGET
            produces:
                - "*/*"
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: OK
                    schema:
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Blogs"
                '401':
                    description: Unauthorized
                '403':
                    description: Forbidden
                '404':
                    description: Not Found
            security:
                - xauth:
                      - global
            deprecated: false
securityDefinitions:
    xauth:
        type: apiKey
        name: my-auth-header
        in: header
definitions:
    Blog:
        type: object
        properties:
            title:
                type: string
        title: Blog
    Blogs:
        type: object
        properties:
            blogs:
                type: array
                items:
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Blog"
        title: Blogs
```

Comment: Any one solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. The invalidity is caused by:

```
security:
    - xauth:
        - global
```

That needs to be:

```
security:
    - xauth: []
```

If you generate the swagger by Java, apply:

```
private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(new SecurityReference("xauth", new AuthorizationScope[0]));
}
```

Comment: this fixes spec validation but breaks the authentication on 'try it out' in swagger-ui.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @igor-lopatka is correct but let's try elaborate it:

1. No empty `AuthorizationScope` list can be used only in case of `OAuth`
   authentication as [scopes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) are entities from `oAuth` World
2. While for others authentication schema, it should be empty

See Example my application support two schemas `BasicAuth` and `OAuth`

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                // skip irrelevant configuration
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(basicAuth(), oAuth2()))
                .securityContexts(singletonList(securityContext()))
                // skip irrelevant configuration
                .build()
    }

    private BasicAuth basicAuth() {
        return new BasicAuth("basicAuth");
    }

    private OAuth oAuth2() {
        return new OAuth("oAuth2", Arrays.asList(oAuth2AuthorizationScopes()), singletonList(new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant("https://example.com/oauth/token"))));
    }

    private AuthorizationScope[] oAuth2AuthorizationScopes() {
        return new AuthorizationScope[]{
               new AuthorizationScope("read", "read access"),
               new AuthorizationScope("write", "write access")
        };
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(regex("/api/.*"))
                .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new SecurityReference("basicAuth", new AuthorizationScope[]{}),
                new SecurityReference("oAuth2", oAuth2AuthorizationScopes())
        );
    }
```